# How to trigger component event in angular dart tests?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, dart

I'm using `angular_test.dart` to test my components. I want to test that clicking on a particular `<li>` will mark it as selected.

**multiple_choice_quiz_component.html**

```
<div>
    <div class="contain-center">
    <h1>{{quiz.getDescription}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="contain-center">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let answer of quiz.getChoiceList"
                (click)="onSelect(answer)"
                [class.selected]="answer == selectedAnswer"
                [class.correct]="correctAnswer && answer == selectedAnswer"
                [class.incorrect]="!correctAnswer && answer == selectedAnswer"
            >
                {{answer}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**multiple_choice_quiz_component.dart**

```
class MultipleChoiceQuizComponent
{
    String selectedAnswer;
    String description;
    bool correctAnswer = false;
    Quiz quiz;

    MultipleChoiceQuizComponent(QuizService quizService)
    {
        this.quiz = quizService.getQuiz();
    }

    void onSelect(String answer)
    {
        selectedAnswer = answer;
        this.correctAnswer = this.quiz.isAnswer(answer);
    }
}
```

**test.dart**

```
...
import 'package:angular_test/angular_test.dart';
....
group('My Tests', () {
    test('should change li element to selected', () async {
    var bed = new NgTestBed<MultipleChoiceQuizComponent>();
    var fixture = await bed.create();
    await fixture.update((MultipleChoiceQuizComponent Component) {
    });
});});
```

In my test, how can I trigger a click on let's say the second `<li>` and evaluate that it has the selected property? And how do I mock the quiz service and inject it to the constructor?

Answer (score 2):

I thought I wasn't going to figure it out, but I did.

Using a [debug html test file](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_api_examples/blob/master/testing/test/issue_body_debug.html) helped a lot. On the console I could set breakpoints. Using the console I could navigate through the methods of these objects to find out what I needed to call.

```
    NgTestBed bed = new NgTestBed<MultipleChoiceQuizComponent>();
    NgTestFixture fixture = await bed.create();
    Element incorrectAnswer = fixture.rootElement.querySelector('.quiz-choice:nth-child(2)');
    incorrectAnswer.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
    bool hasClass = incorrectAnswer.classes.contains('incorrect');
    expect(true, hasClass);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PageObjects to interact with the page:
https://github.com/google/pageloader

Comment: How is it used for an example like mine?